# How to get evidence that each type element in Shapeless HList belongs to a typeclass

Tags: scala, shapeless

I've tried the following:

```
trait Evidence[H <: HList, T[_]] {}

object Evidence {
  implicit def HNilEvidence[T[_]] = new Evidence[HNil, T] {}
  implicit def HListEvidence[Head, Remaining <: HList, T[_]](implicit headEv: T[Head], remainingEv: Evidence[Remaining, T]) =
    new Evidence[Head :: Remaining, T] {}
}
```

This correctly gives me an implicit evidence, only when all elements match a typeclass.

But, when trying to use it like this (a contrived example):

```
def transform[A](a: A)(implicit ev: Evidence[A :: HNil, Ordering]) =
   { List(a,a).sorted }
```

this gives the error

```
error: No implicit Ordering defined for A.
```

which should be there based on presence of `Evidence[A :: HNil, Ordering]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to define your own `Evidence` type class. Use shapeless' `ops.hlist.LiftAll`.

```
def transform[A](a: A)(implicit
                                     liftAll: LiftAll.Aux[Ordering, A :: HNil, Ordering[A] :: HNil],
                                     isHCons: IsHCons.Aux[Ordering[A] :: HNil, Ordering[A], HNil]): List[A] = {
  implicit val ordering: Ordering[A] = liftAll.instances.head
  List(a, a).sorted
}
```

Comment: The implicit evidence `isHCons` is actually not required because it is available for any cons list, which `Ordering[A] :: HNil` already is.

https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/shapeless/ops/hlists.scala#L45-L54

Answer (score 1):

Why not express the contents of the List with an `LUB` and simply move the request for ordering evidence at the method level? The typeclass bit here is misleading, what you are matching seems to be a `type` unless I'm missing the obvious, not a type-class or a type-family.

`LUBConstraint` already exists in Shapeless for this reason.

```
class Transformer[HL <: HList, T](list: T :: HL)(
  implicit val c: LUBConstraint[HL, T]
) {
  def transform(obj: List[T])(
    implicit ev: Ordering[T],
    toList: ToList[T :: HL, T]
  ): List[T] = (toList(list) ::: obj).sorted(ev.reverse)
}
```

I also don't really understand why you need the `A` type param and what the relation is between `A` and the `LUB`. I've added an example for you just to make a point, hopefully it's useful enough to show you how to combine things.

```
val list = "test3" :: "test1" :: "test2" :: HNil
val listb = List("test5", "test4", "test6")
val transformer = new Transformer(list)

transformer.transform(listb) shouldEqual List(
  "test6",
  "test5",
  "test4",
  "test3",
  "test2",
  "test1"
)
```